# Android App does not work on run time taking some time to work, how to solve this issue

Tags: java, android, performance

I am new in android development and learning android apps development. I have created a very basic and simple Flashlight for android device. I am facing the issue when i run the app it takes some time to run like if i press turn on flash light it will take some time (half sec or less but it take some time), i didn't use wait() method in my app. How to run it really fast like user click on it flash turn on or turn off?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton imageButton;
private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
private Camera.Parameters params;
private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.switch_btn);

    //Check that Device has supports flash or not

    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash){
        //If device does not supports Flash
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your current device does not support to Little Flashy! ops");
        alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Close application
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }


    //Get the Camera
    getCamera();
    //Display button image
    toggleButtonImage();

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                turnOffFlash();
            } else

            {
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void toggleButtonImage() {
    if (isFlashOn){
        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_on);}
    else {imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_switch_off);}

    }

private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null){
        try{
            camera = camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }catch (RuntimeException e){
            Log.d("Camera Error.", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Turning On flash
 */
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}

/*
 * Turning Off flash
 */
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}

private void playSound() {
    if (isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_off);}
    else {
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //turn off flash when on Pause called
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (hasFlash) turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (camera != null){
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add some code where this lag is coming

Comment: please provide an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado if you ever want a shortcut use put mcve in [ ] and that will automatically link to the page that you linked to

Comment: question updated and also code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you turn the flash on and off, you call the `playSound` method, which uses the `MediaPlayer`. this method is slow and causes your delay. First try to remove it (by commenting it out) and see the difference. Next, you can try to run it from a thread.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have run the app without sound and it is working fine no delay at all. Now what i need to do? where i need to call the playsound(); method?

Comment: It's hard to tell. Try to call the MediaPlayer's `create` as soon as you can so it will be ready as soon as possible, and play the sound with `start` only when the user presses the button.

Comment: i think without sound it is perfect as user will not mind if there is no sound when he turn on or turn off flash. In future will add this sound function with more feature in new update of app. thanks for help TDG.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can ignore the sound feature for current time. Or if you really want this feature than use it through Thread it will show no lag or delay in your app while user turn on or turn off flash.